# Decode h264 stream with ffmpeg introduces a delay, how to avoid?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I'm working on some code that encodes a video feed, sends it over UDP to a client that then decodes the stream. It working fine using a x264 encoder, my only problem is that when i call `avcodec_decode_video2` on the incomming frame, the decoder introduces a delay as if it has an internal buffer. How can i avoid this? What is controlling this behavior? Is it the encoder that should be changed, or is it missing settings in the decoder context? Currently i just create the decoder context with defaults `avcodec_get_context_defaults3`.

The encoder has the following parameters:

```
x264_param_t param;
x264_param_default_preset(&param, preset.c_str(), "zerolatency");
param.i_frame_reference = 1;

param.i_threads = 1;
param.b_sliced_threads = 5;
param.i_slice_max_size = 8192;
param.i_width = width;
param.i_height = height;
param.i_fps_num = 30;
param.i_fps_den = 1;
param.i_sync_lookahead = 0;

param.i_bframe = 0;
// Intra refres:
param.i_keyint_max = 30;
param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
//Rate control:
param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
param.rc.i_lookahead = 0;
param.rc.i_bitrate = bitrate;
param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = bitrate;
param.rc.i_vbv_buffer_size = bitrate/30;

//For streaming:
param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
param.b_annexb = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you use frame-threading during decoding and that cause frame buffering. The only other reason I know is use of B-frames but you disabled it during encoding. Btw "param.b_sliced_threads = 5;" looks strange knowing that b_sliced_threads is boolean value.